# How to not worry about children objects (lists) in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have a parent object called **Request** and a Child object called **RequestDate**

A **Request** has a list of **RequestDates**

i want to have mappings so when i:

1. Save Parent, it saves all children
2. Update list on parent object (remove some items and add some new items) and save parent it updates children
3. Delete parent will delete all children.

is this possible.  i tried using this syntax but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 HasMany(x => x.RequestDates)
     .AsBag()
     .Inverse()
     .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
     .Fetch.Select()
     .BatchSize(80);
```

the issue is around #2.  what is the way to update the list of items.  I am calling Remove() to get rid of some and then calling Add() to add new ones

Comment: Which part isn't working? That is how you would do it AFAIK. Post your objects and the RequestDate mapping.

Comment: What does your RequestDate mapping look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've configured your collection as `Inverse`, which means the "other side" (i.e. a  `References` in RequestDate) is responsible for managing the relationship.

Therefore, you need to set the reference to the Request in the RequestDate.

If you don't have such a property, then remove the `Inverse()` call. But NH will do an insert with NULL and then an UPDATE, which might not be what you want.